# JFrame no muestra mi imagen cuando la pillo desde un getImage()

Tags: java, imagen, java-swing, jframe

Para un trabajo de clase decidí hacer el uno con interfaz gráfica, pero me he topado con un problema, yo tengo una clase cartas donde guardo el número, el color y la imagen de esta, si yo en la Vista(que es donde tengo el JFrame) hago esto no hay problema:

```
JLabel prueba = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\david\\img\\Negro\\C4Negro.png"));
```

Pero si intento acceder a ella a traves de carta no me deja:

```
//jug es el jugador, que tiene un atributo mano, que es un array de Cartas del cual cojo la imagen.
JLabel prueba2 = new JLabel(jug.getMano().get(0).getImagen());
```

Tengo claro que todo funcina menos getImagen porque hago lo mismo pero con el nombre y
lo muestro en pantalla y aparece en el frame perfectamente.

Aqui os dejo las clases Vista, Carta y Jugador simplificadas:

Vista:

```
public class Vista extends JFrame{
    public Vista(String titulo){
        super(titulo);
        JLabel hola2 = new JLabel(jug.getMano().get(0).getImagen();
        add(prueba);
        setSize(1000, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Carta:

```
public class Carta {
    
    private Color color;
    private int numero;
    private ImageIcon imagen;
    
    
    public Carta(Color color, int numero, ImageIcon imagen){
        this.color = color;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public ImageIcon getImagen(){
        return imagen;
    }

}
```

Jugador:

```
public class Jugador {
    
    private String nombreUsuario;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mano;


    public ArrayList<Carta> getMano() {
        return mano;
    }
```

Muchas gracias por ller

Comment: Debería ser `return this.imagen;` en el método `getImagen()`, ¿cierto? Te falta indicarle `this`.

Comment: Supongo que lo mismo te sucede en la Clase `Jugador` con el método `getMano()`, te haría falta indicar `this`. Es decir, deberías retornar lo siguiente: `return this.mano;`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, hola, no, el this se usa cuando hay conflicto de nombres, o cuando quieres pasar el objeto como parámetro, por ejemplo, en el constructor puedes escribir lo siguiente: **public LaClase( int num ) {  numero = num; }** y funciona perfectamente. Loko8, podrías mostrarnos como inicializas la carta?.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, era un problema de como guardaba la ruta de las imagenes, que no funcionaba por no ponerle la extension png al final, pero aun asi muchas gracias.